# Перевести из c# в php

Tags: php, c#

Перевёл этот код из сей в пхп, но он работает неправильно

```
generateConfirmationHashForTime(long time, string tag)
{
    byte[] decode = Convert.FromBase64String(this.IdentitySecret);
    int n2 = 8;
    if (tag != null)
    {
        if (tag.Length > 32)
        {
            n2 = 8 + 32;
        }
        else
        {
            n2 = 8 + tag.Length;
        }
    }
    byte[] array = new byte[n2];
    int n3 = 8;
    while (true)
    {
        int n4 = n3 - 1;
        if (n3 <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        array[n4] = (byte)time;
        time >>= 8;
        n3 = n4;
    }
    if (tag != null)
    {
        Array.Copy(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tag), 0, array, 8, n2 - 8);
    }

    HMACSHA1 hmacGenerator = new HMACSHA1();
    hmacGenerator.Key = decode;
    byte[] hashedData = hmacGenerator.ComputeHash(array);
    string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedData, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    string hash = WebUtility.UrlEncode(encodedData);
    return hash;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function generateConfirmationHashForTime($time, $tag = null) {
    $identity_secret = 'FQagvnTM+3UbQISB4Ry5p1XJQ4s=';

    $n2 = 8;

    if ($tag !== null) {
        if (strlen($tag) > 32) {
            $n2 = 8 + 32;
        } else {
            $n2 = 8 + strlen($tag);
        }
    }

    $arr = array();
    $n3 = 8;
    while (1) {
        $n4 = $n3 - 1;
        if ($n3 <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        $arr[$n4] = 0x00FF & $time;
        $time >>= 8;
        $n3 = $n4;
    }

    if ($tag !== null) {
        $tag_bytes = unpack('C*', $tag);
        //$arr = array_splice($arr, 8, $n2 - 8, $tag_bytes);
        $arr = array_merge(array_slice($arr, 0, 8), $tag_bytes);
    }


    $hashedData = hash_hmac ("sha1" , base64_encode(call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $arr))), $identity_secret, true) ;
    $encodedData = base64_encode($hashedData);
    $hash = urlencode($encodedData);
    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Массивы в `php` совсем не тоже самое, что в `c#`. К примеру, при:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[7] = 'seven';
```

не произойдет увеличения массива до 8-ми элементов и новый элемент не запишется в конец. В пустой массив добавится строка `seven` с ключом `1`, и количество элементов станет равно 1. Смещение нового элемента будет равно 0 (первый элемент). Т.е:

```
/*вместо*/ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'seven']
/*будет */ [7 => 'seven']
```

Функция `array_slice` возвращает срез массива и учитывает смещение, а не ключи. В срезе элементы будут следовать в том порядке в котором они добавлялись.

Это можно исправить - нужно инициализировать массив (как в оригинале).

```
- $arr = array();
+ $arr = array_fill(0, $n2, 0);
```

Далее, вы не так как в оригинале генерируете `hmac`. Не нужно кодировать в `base64` полученный массив и нужно декодировать `$identity_secret`.

```
- $hashedData = hash_hmac ("sha1" , base64_encode(call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $arr))), $identity_secret, true) ;
+ $hashedData = hash_hmac ("sha1" , call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $arr)), base64_decode($identity_secret), true) ;
```

пробовать [c#](http://ideone.com/Cst5J1), [php](http://ideone.com/rH739J)